# Using multiprocessing with a decorated function results in a PicklingError

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to write a convenience function based on the `multiprocessing` library, that takes any function and argument, and runs that function using multiple processes. I have the following file "MultiProcFunctions.py" that I am importing:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager

def MultiProcDecorator(f,*args):

    """
    Takes a function f, and formats it so that results are saved to a shared dict
    """

    def g(procnum,return_dict,*args):
        result = f(*args)
        return_dict[procnum] = result

    return g

def MultiProcFunction(f,n_procs,*args):
    """
    Takes a function f, and runs it in n_procs with given args
    """

    manager     = Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    jobs = []
    for i in range(n_procs):
        p = multiprocessing.Process( target = f, args = (i,return_dict) + args )
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()

    return dict(return_dict)
```

Here is the code I run:

```
from MultiProcFunctions import *

def sq(x):
    return [i**2 for i in x]

g = MultiProcDecorator(sq)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    result = MultiProcFunction(g,2,[1,2,3])
```

I get the following error: `PicklingError: Can't pickle <function g at 0x01BD83B0>: it's not found as MultiProcFunctions.g`

If I use the following definition for `g` instead, everything is fine:

```
def g(procnum,return_dict,x):
    result = [i**2 for i in x]
    return_dict[procnum] = result
```

Why is are the two definitions of `g` different, and is there any thing I can do to get the original `g` definition to "work"?

Comment: Is there anything in the code sample without which the error still results? If you remove it, it could help with finding the answer to your question.

Comment: What is wrong with using ready solution like Celery?

Comment: Puicek, didn't know about Celery, looking into it now. APerson: I edited the question so it contains the minimal code possible, maybe that will make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: @kyphos it should fit your use case. And if you want to grab someones attention in the future, make sure to add "@" in front of their name ;).

Comment: In your example `g` is local to `MultiProcessingDecorator`. One of the limitations of `pickle` is that it only [allows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) serializing globally defined functions. To overcome this you can make `MultiProcessingDecorator` a class and implement the `pickle` [protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `g` is actually defined as a nested function in `MultiProcFunctions`, which means it's not actually importable from the top-level of that module, which means it won't pickle properly. Now, we're actually pretty clearly defining `g` in the top-level of `__main__` module though, when we do this:

```
g = MultiProcDecorator(sq)
```

So, it really *should* be picklable. We can make it work by explicitly setting the `__module__` of `g` to be `"__main__"`:

```
g = MultiProcDecorator(sq)
g.__module__ = "__main__"  # Fix the __module__
```

This will allow the pickling process to work, since it will look for the definition of `g` in `__main__`, where it is defined at the top-level, rather than `MultiProcFunctions`, where it is only defined in a nested scope.

**Edit:**

Note that you could also make the change in the decorator itself:

```
def MultiProcDecorator(f,*args):

    """
    Takes a function f, and formats it so that results are saved to a shared dict
    """

    def g(procnum,return_dict,*args):
        result = f(*args)
        return_dict[procnum] = result
    g.__module__ = "__main__"

    return g
```

This probably makes more sense for you, since this decorator is strictly meant to be using for `multiprocessing` purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Trying [dano's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26577483/4433) seem to only works in Python 2. When trying in Python 3, I get the following error:

> `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function serialize at 0x7f7a1ac1fd08>: it's not the same object as __main__.orig_fn`

I solved this issue by "decorating" function from worker's init:

```
from functools import wraps
import sys

def worker_init(fn, *args):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(x):
        # wrapper logic
        pass

    setattr(sys.modules[fn.__module__], fn.__name__, wrapper)

pool = mp.Pool(initializer=worker_init, initargs=[orig_fn, *args])
# ...
```

Comment: nice! I searched for a proper workaround quite a while and this one does the job perfectly!